# Жи Ши в личных именах.

Tags: заимствования, ономастика

Впервые в таком положении... Роюсь в интернете уже неделю...
Первое что мне вдолбили на уроках родной речи Жи Ши пиши с И, и даже не ответили почему... и вот пере до мной сидит ЖЫлдыз... уроженка КИргИзии (с этим разобрался), но с российским паспортом, в котором жЫ...
Так и должно быть или произошла чудовищная ошибка?

Comment: спасибо всем!!!
Классный сайт!

Answer (score 1):

Ну для начала. Правила орфографии в большинстве своём для написания имён собственных не действуют. Кроме некоторых базовых: написания с заглавной буквы и т.п.. Имена-фамилии (а зачастую топонимы и прочее) правильно писать так, как они написаны в документах.

Но вообще-то вопрос очень не простой. Когда-то давно, при переводе писменностей народов СССР на кириллицу было принято решение, что в киргизском (и некоторых других языках) подобные и многие другие, не свойственные русскому языку, сочетания могут использоваться для отражения особенностей произношения. До причин докапываться сейчас бесполезно, возможно в конкретном случае действительно руководствовались большей твердостью согласного.
Поэтому достаточно логично сохранять такое написание для имён, изначально написанных кириллицей. Но вот что будет происходить с переводом языков народов бывшего СССР на латиницу - трудно сказать.  Разнобой возникает очень серьёзный.

Comment: и всё же... Ведь есть правило (норматив?) писать Киргизия, а не Кыргызия, как настаивают киргизы...
В именах ничего подобного нет?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, тут все-таки уместно Ы. Дело в том, что в тюркских языках слог "жи" произносится тверже, чем в русском - там слышится явное "жЫ". Ведь пишут же в некоторых заимствованных словах и иностранных именах Ю после Ш.

Answer (score 0):

И вообще с документом не поспоришь, уж как не хочется писать"Каменьшиков" - а приходится: так в паспорте. А Ельцин?(Вместо Ельцын) Тоже ведь не по правилу..  И Пугачёва (Вместо Пугачова)

Answer (score 0):

Русское написание ЖИ, ШИ  традиционное. Раньше Ш и Ж обозначали мягкие согласные [ш'] и  [ж'], поэтому после них писалось И. В современном русском языке Ж и Ш отвердели, но написание И после этих согласных осталось. При подготовке реформ орфографии вопрос о том, чтобы писать ЖЫ и ШЫ, поднимался неоднократно. Что касается иностранных имён и фамилий, особенно если они записаны кириллицей в паспорте, - ничего не поделаешь. Но ровно то же происходит, когда мы пытаемся транслитерировать русские (белорусские, украинские) имена и фамилии с нашими Ч, Щ   на какой-нибудь немецкий язык, а еще лучше на китайский :-)